# how to convert Django 2.0 url() to path()

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am unable to convert URL to path. how can I do that? and how to pass id on it.
code is following.

```
urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^$',views.index, name="index"),
    #192.0.0.1/polls/
    url(r'^(?p<question_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.detail,name="detail"),
    #192.0.0.1/polls/1
    url(r'^(?p<question_id>[0-9]+)/result$',views.results, name="result"),
    #192.0.0.1/polls/results
    url(r'^(?p<question_id>[0-9]+)/votes$',views.vote, name="vote"),
    #192.0.0.1/polls/results
    ]
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#re-path

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample urls for django 2.0

**try this**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name="detail"),
    path('<int:question_id>/result', views.results, name="result"),
    .....
]
```

or using [regex](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    re_path(r'^/(?P<question_id>[0-9])/$', views.detail,name="detail"),
    re_path(r'^/(?P<question_id>[0-9])/result$', views.results, name="result"),
    .....
]
```

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/)